# Python OperationalError: no such table: log

Tags: python

I am trying to add a simple check in Python for login screen but its not working. I am beginner so please help me to understand what I am doing wrong. Following is the check and relevant dependencies.

```
def check():
    global un, pwd, login, l, root
    u=un.get()
    p=pwd.get()
    l.execute("select * from log")
    for i in l:
        if i[0]==u and i[1]==p and u=='admin':
            root.destroy()
            open_win()
        elif i[0]==u and i[1]==p:
            root.destroy()
            open_cus()
        elif i[0]==u or i[1]==p:
            top=Tk()
            Label(top,width=30, text='Wrong Password or Username').grid(row=0, column=0)
            top.mainloop()
    login.commit()

def main_menu(): #controls open and close of main menu window----------------------------------------RETURN TO MAIN MENU
    global sto, apt, flag, root, st, val, exp, st1,rev
    if flag=='sto':
        sto.destroy()
    if flag=='rev':
        rev.destroy()
    elif flag=='st':
        st.destroy()
    elif flag=='st1':
        st1.destroy()
    elif flag=='val':
        val.destroy()
    elif flag=='exp':
        exp.destroy()
    elif flag=='d':
        d.destroy()
    open_win()

def main_cus():
    global st, flag, exp
    if flag=='exp':
        exp.destroy()
    elif flag=='st':
        st.destroy()
    open_cus()

def open_cus(): #OPENS MAIN MENU----------------------------------------------------------------------------MAIN MENU
    global apt, flag, flags
    flags='apt1'
    apt=Tk()
    apt.title("Interface")
    Label(apt, text="MEDPLUS CHEMIST AND DRUGGIST").grid(row=0,column=0)
    Label(apt, text='*'*40).grid(row=1,column=0)
    Label(apt, text='*  WELCOME  *').grid(row=2,column=0)
    Label(apt, text='-'*40).grid(row=3,column=0)
    Label(apt, text="Customer Services").grid(row=4,column=0)
    Label(apt, text='-'*40).grid(row=5,column=0)
    Button(apt,text='Search', width=15, command=search).grid(row=6,column=0)
    Button(apt,text='Expiry Check', width=15, command=exp_date).grid(row=7,column=0)
    Label(apt, text='-'*40).grid(row=8,column=0)
    Button(apt,text='Logout',command=again).grid(row=9, column=0)
    apt.mainloop()

again()
```

Login Initialization:

```
login=sqlite.connect("admin.sqlite")
l=login.cursor()
#l.execute('''CREATE TABLE log(user, password)''')
#l.execute("INSERT INTO log VALUES ('admin','123456')")
login.commit()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Shazia/med_mgmt.py", line 730, in check
    l.execute("select * from log")
OperationalError: no such table: log
```

Comment: The error message is clear enough. You don't have a table `log` in your database.

Comment: The table log exists but I don't know why it's not accessible by python.

Comment: where is the `l` initialized? Maybe you need to specify the database or  initialize the handle correctly?

Comment: I updated the code where "l" initialized.

Comment: The table is clearly not there. Perhaps you are connecting to a different database than you think you are.